# Copying Files Build Phase is not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, objective-c++

I am trying to get absolute path for my json files in run time from .cpp files. This is the code I am using to get absolute path,

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
        CFURLRef resourcesURL = CFBundleCopyResourcesDirectoryURL(mainBundle);
        char path[PATH_MAX];
        if (!CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(resourcesURL, TRUE, (UInt8 *)path, PATH_MAX)) {
            CELogW("Cant read the filepath: %s", filePath.c_str());
        }
        CFRelease(resourcesURL);
        chdir(path);
```

Also I added my .json file to build phase as shown in the image

[image]

This really works fine in my system. But when I run the same code in another system these files are missing in build directory.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find any solution for this. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project on either system? Are the json files present on the other system? (e.g. is the path Xcode is looking present?)

Comment: Ya I tried cleaning. Yes the other system also having all the files in copy files build phase. But in run time these files are not copied to build directory.

Comment: If there anything in the build log during the copy-files build phase?

Comment: No there is no log. I am not sure whether I made any changes to my xcode. Is there anything I need to change in xcode settings ?

Comment: I meant the build log. Look at the detailed build log and see if anything is complaining. You might also try and make a small sample project and see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Fine I will look into build log. But do you think any changes are required in xcode settings ?

Comment: I don't think there are likely to be Xcode settings that would break copying files. A small sample program might help confirm that.

Comment: Ok I will create one sample and look into that. Thanks !

Comment: @JesseRusak Its really awkward, Even if I remove copy files build phase from my project settings it still works fine for me. I am not sure how this is happening. Could you please explain me how to make copy files build phase ? I am totally confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some quite long research I have found what I missed. I should have kept my destination as `Product Directory` not Resources. Also I made new Run script as follows,

```
#!/bin/bash

SRC="${PROJECT_DIR}/Libraries/fileName.json"
DEST="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}${EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME}/${FULL_PRODUCT_NAME}"
cp -R "$SRC" "$DEST"
```

Now everything works like charm. Thanks @Jesse Rusak for your valuable time.